# Creating dynamic proxy class from "object representation"

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, reflection, types

Is it possible to create an object model representation of an actual class that can be turned into a real class again which fits the signature of the origin for using it as some sort of dynamic proxy?

Currently, I've got a plugin API / interfaces inside my application which looks like this (simplified dummy):

```
public interface IPlugin {
    void Initialize();
    void SendData(DataObject data);
}
```

A `DataObject` could look like this:

```
public class DataObject {
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
}
```

With this interface, I can send whatever kind of data I like to a plugin, however it has a few drawbacks:

- It's not really extensible
- The plugin needs to manually parse/interpret the data
- I can send complete gibberish to the plugin
- I need an additional specification to specifiy how the data has to look like.

What I'd like to have is a plugin interface that could be extended like this:

```
public interface IPlugin :
    ICanReceive<ArbitaryClass1>,
    ICanReceive<ArbitaryClass2>
{
    // implements void Receive(ArbitaryClass1 value);
    // implements void Receive(ArbtiaryClass2 value);
}
```

The plugin would provide the classes itself without having the main application to know about these types. In order to make this work, I thought about the following:

- Reflect the generic parameters of the interfaces the plugin implements
- Map the types into a "object model", which could look like this:

Example

```
interface IType {
    + TypeKind (e.g. primitive, structured, reference, collection)
}

interface IStructuredType : IType {
    + collection of <IPropertyType>
    + StructuredTypeKind (e.g. complex, entity)
}
```

- Persist the object model in a database for value editing
- Upon sending the data to the plugin, create *proxy* classes out of the object model with the same signature that was originally reflected from the types, thus matching the methods of `ICanReceive<'T>`

My question is: How could such a thing work (especially the dynamic proxy stuff)? How could this be done? `Reflection.Emit`? *CodeDOM*? There are already certain standards to represent an object model, such as *EDM* (used in *EntityFramework*, *OData*) and AFAIK, *Entity Framework* already returns dynamic proxy objects for stuff like lazy loading when accessing entities from a `DbSet<'T>`, so there must be a way to do this. :)